# Fazer Update de tabela de item com estoque em qualquer filial

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Tudo bem Pessoal,

Tenho uma tabela com estoque dos produtos de uma rede com 13 lojas. Quero bloquear os itens que não tem estoque em nenhuma loja e que não tiveram vendas no ultimo ano ou que só foram cadastrados, mas não venderam. Tentei o script abaixo:

```
UPDATE PRXLJ
SET  Flg_BlqCom = 1, Flg_BlqVen = 1
WHERE Qtd_Saldo= 0
AND (YEAR(Dat_UltVen) <2017
OR Dat_UltVen IS NULL)
```

onde:

- Flg_BlqCom = 1 bloqueado para compra
- Flg_BlqVen = 1 bloqueado para venda
- Flg_BlqCom = 0 desbloqueado para compra
- Flg_BlqVen = 0 desbloqueado para venda

O problema é que mesmo no servidor central os estoques estão distribuídos na tabela loja a loja e não quero bloquear se tiver pelo menos uma unidade em qualquer filial. o mesmo codigo de produto se repete 13 vezes, um para cada loja. 
Quando rodei esse script ele bloqueou os produtos de acordo com o estoque e ultima venda de cada loja, bloqueando um produto em algumas lojas e em outras não.

A estrutura da tabela é assim:

[image: Tabela de estoque de produtos]

Preciso de um script que faça bloqueio apenas do produto que não tem estoque em nenhuma loja e que não teve venda após 01/01/2017 em nenhuma loja também.

Uso Sql Server 2008
Esta tabela possui por volta de 60 mil itens (considerando que são 13 lojas, ficam por volta de 780mil linhas) e quero deixar desbloqueado uns 15mil itens ou menos que de fato são ativos. Por questões fiscais não posso apagar os itens antigos, apenas bloquea-los. 
Não sei se as informações foram suficientes para compreensão, mas caso precisem de mais dados me avisem.

Comment: São servidores diferentes ? você consegue fazer um select em cada servidor ? se sim você vai precisar fazer um join entre as tabelas dos servidores fazendo os seus where e ands para casa um ... um caso bem trabalhoso mas que vai ser necessário para o que você quer.

Comment: Veja esse select ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144070/2740371 você vai precisa fazer um update com base nas tabelas de cada servidor.filial.

Comment: @GPDias A versão do SQL Server é 2008 ou 2008 R2? A edição é a Enterprise?

Comment: A versão é 2008 R2 @JoséDiz. Cada loja possui um servidor, mas as alterações de cadastro são feitas em um servidor central que fica no escritório. Nele a tabela PRXLJ tem o estoque de todas as lojas. Se a alteração for feita na filial o sistema possui um sync que irá atualizar de acordo com o que está no servidor central. Então alterações no servidor da filial não surte efeito, pois será restabelecido o cadastro do central após termino da sincronização.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se a sugestão a seguir atende ao que necessita.

```
-- código #1 v2
with Bloquear as (
SELECT Cod_produt
  from PRxLJ
  group by Cod_produt
  having max (Qtd_Saldo) = 0
         and max (coalesce(year(Dat_UltVen), 0)) < 2017
)
UPDATE PRxLJ
  set Flg_BlqCom = 1, Flg_BlqVen = 1
  where Cod_Produt in (SELECT Cod_produt from Bloquear);
```

O código acima assume que sempre haverá informação na coluna Qtd_Saldo e que ela jamais será negativa.

---

A respeito de sua segunda pergunta, *desbloquear o que não deveria estar bloqueado*, eis uma opção:

```
-- código #2
with Liberar as (
SELECT Cod_produt
  from PRxLJ
  where Flg_BlqCom = 1
        and Flg_BlqVen = 1
  group by Cod_produt
  having max (Qtd_Saldo) > 0
         or max (coalesce(year(Dat_UltVen), 0)) >= 2017
)
UPDATE PRxLJ
  set Flg_BlqCom = 0, Flg_BlqVen = 0
  where Cod_Produt in (SELECT Cod_produt from Liberar);
```

Para que o arquivo de log de transações não cresça muito, a CTE `Liberar` somente retorna os produtos que estejam bloqueados em ao menos uma loja e que atendam aos requisitos. Por isso foi acrescentada a cláusula WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, solução perfeita. Tentei fazer algo parecido, mas não consegui. Caso eu queira fazer o inverso também, desbloquear o que tem saldo ou venda em alguma loja, o código abaixo tá certo?

```
    with Liberado as (
SELECT Cod_produt
  from PRxLJ
  group by Cod_produt
  having sum (Qtd_Saldo) <> 0
         or max (coalesce(year(Dat_UltVen), 0)) > 2017
)
UPDATE PRxLJ
  set Flg_BlqCom = 0, Flg_BlqVen = 0
  where Cod_Produt in (SELECT Cod_produt from Liberado);
```